# Which dependencies should i not obfuscate with proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

i imported these dependencies in my android project:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

compile project(':openCVLibrary330')
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

}

Now my question is: which dependencies should i not obfuscate with proguard and how to achieve this result?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you wouldn't have to worry about this at all. Dependencies come with their own Proguard file, which is merged with your own when the app is built. Google's libraries definitely follow this rule. The only time you would have to worry about it is when you use some third-party library that's not well designed. In that case you would have to check if the library uses reflection anywhere to reference any methods or classes, in which case you would have to exclude those methods or classes from being obfuscated.

Comment: Well, I understand. For example, in my project I use third-party libraries like openCV and circleImageView. If I understood correctly I should specify in the proguard-rules.pro file not to obfuscate these two dependencies by writing `-keep class org.opencv.*`? Is this the correct syntax? Thanks so much.